# Using Discord.js, how can I trigger a bot when a webhook is triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot in a server (for example purposes, let’s say the server is called “John’s Server”), so, in John’s Server, there is also a webhook.

What I want to do is, whenever a webhook message is sent in John’s server, the bot sends a message in a channel. (For the example, let’s say the channel ID id 1234567890)

So, if the webhook in John’s Server with the ID 0000000000 is used to send a message, the bot sends a message in channel 1234567890.

How is this possible? (Using Discord.js, by the way)

Answer (score -1):

To do this you'll have to listen to the `message` event, when it fires you'll check the [`Message#webhookID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=webhookID%5C) property. If it has a truthy value then the message is sent from a webhook, otherwise it's sent from a user.
Then all you need to do is get the channel from the server and send the message.

Here's an example:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.webhookID) return; // If the message isn't from a webhook, don't do anything
  const channel = message.guild.channels.fetch("0123456789");
  // Using the fetch method, discord.js will check the cache first, if the channel is there
  // then it will return it, otherwise discord.js will hit the Discord API and get the channel
  
  channel.send(`
A message from ${message.author.username} (${message.webhookID}) has been sent in 
${message.channel.name}.
Message: ${message.url}
  `);
});
```